# Perl or xslt: convert XML schema named type to anonymous type

Tags: xml, perl, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am trying to convert named complex type to anonymous type in XML Schema using Perl script or xslt.

The element name and type could be anything dynamic.

XML schema example:

```
<xsd:element name="person" type="Person"/>
<xsd:element name="person2" type="Person"/>
<xsd:complexType name="Person">
  <xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:element name="first" type="xsd:string"/>
    <xsd:element name="last" type="xsd:string"/>
  </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

Will be converted to:

```
<xsd:element name="person">
  <xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="first" type="xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:element name="last" type="xsd:string"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
<xsd:element name="person2">
  <xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="first" type="xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:element name="last" type="xsd:string"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: That looks right to me, or are you asking how to convert it programmatically?

Comment: Yes, to write a Perl or xslt script to convert it automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just an XML file, so use your favorite XML parser.

```
use XML::LibXML               qw( );
use XML::LibXML::XPathContext qw( );

sub resolve_qname {
   my ($context_node, $qname) = @_;
   my $local_part = $qname;
   my $namespace = $local_part =~ s/^([^:]*)://
       ? $context_node->lookupNamespaceURI($1) // $1 : '';
   return "{$namespace}$local_part";
}

my $in_qfn  = '...';
my $out_qfn = '...';

my $parser = XML::LibXML->new();
my $doc    = $parser->parse_file($in_qfn);
my $root   = $doc->documentElement();

my $xpc = XML::LibXML::XPathContext->new();
$xpc->registerNs(xs => 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema');

my %unsupported;

my %type_nodes_by_name;
for my $type_node ($xpc->findnodes('xs:complexType', $root)) {
   my $type_name = $type_node->getAttribute('name')
      or next;

   $type_node->removeAttribute('name');
   $type_nodes_by_name{resolve_qname($type_node, $type_name)} = $type_node;
}

for my $element_node ($xpc->findnodes('//xs:element', $root)) {
   my $type_name = $element_node->getAttribute('type')
      or next;

   my $type_node = $type_nodes_by_name{resolve_qname($element_node, $type_name)}
      or next;

   $element_node->removeAttribute('type');
   $element_node->appendChild($type_node->cloneNode(1));
}

for my $type_node (values(%type_nodes_by_name)) {
   $type_node->parentNode()->removeChild($type_node);
}

$doc->toFile($out_qfn);
```

Input:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xsd:element name="person" type="Person"/>
  <xsd:element name="person2" type="Person"/>
  <xsd:complexType name="Person">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="first" type="xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:element name="last" type="xsd:string"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

Output (after prettification):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xsd:element name="person">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="first" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="last" type="xsd:string"/>
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
  <xsd:element name="person2">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="first" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="last" type="xsd:string"/>
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

`resolve_qname` isn't [accurate](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/#src-resolve), but probably good enough.

Comment: Thanks @ikegami, your script works for fixed name and type, I am pretty sure that with some modification it will work with dynamic elements and recursively! To be verified!

Comment: Update to handle all complex types.